# Stored Procedure fails after added one parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getGameIdByPlayerAndDate`(out id integer)
BEGIN
-- DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
select game
from `playerstatistic`, `game`
where `playerstatistic`.`game`=`game`.`id`
    and `date`="2014-03-26"
    and `PlayerName`="Kenneth Faried";

    -- open myCursor;
    -- FETCH myCursor INTO id;  


    -- set id=0;


    -- SELECT id;  
    -- SET id=2;  
    -- SELECT id;  
END
```

I wanted to pass player name and date, and the procedure returns the game id. But now for trouble shooting, I hard coded the player name and date.

I call the procedure, it selects the correct data.
[image]

Then I add `playerName` parameter to the procedure, and add a dummy argument to the call statement. The store procedure selects nothing now!

[image]

Do I write anything wrong? How to make the code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign the value passed as parameter:

First, change the name to avoid duplicate names:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getGameIdByPlayerAndDate`(IN p_playerName varchar(40),out id integer)
```

Now assign this parameter to PlayerName field

```
`PlayerName` = p_playerName;
```

Comment: I didn't use the parameter at all. Does the parameter matters?

Comment: I changed the name of the parameter from playerName to testName, then the procedure works as before. It seems somehow the parameter overrides the column of the table. I want to know why.

Comment: it happens because MySQL don't discrimine paramters variable names of table field names.

Comment: Besides changing the name, there is another solution which is to fully qualify the column name, ie. `and playerstatistic.PlayerName=PlayerName;`